# php preg_match, how to switch values

Tags: php, preg-match

Please help with this little issue if you could.

I would like to search a string, if a match is made, I'd like to change the value to something else.

eg.

```
if (preg_match("gmail",$email)) {

// code needed to switch "gmail" for "googlemail"

}
```

This is needed because my mail server won't accept an email address in 'gmail.com' format.

Thanks in advance. Shane

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need regular expressions just use str_replace. No need to test either, just replace it.

```
str_replace( '@gmail.com', '@googlemail.com', $email );
```

Comment: Shane: That code will change something like `gmail4353@gmail.com` to `googlemail4353@googlemail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Just so it doesn't match something like `mygmail@gmail.com`:

```
$email = preg_replace('/(.+)gmail(\..+)$/', '$1googlemail$2', $email);
```

Comment: this will change mygmail.email@yahoo.com to mygooglemail.email@yahoo.com and you forgot the trailing /

Comment: Why the `(\..+)$`? Are there other [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)s besides the `.com` of `gmail`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace("gmail", "googlemail", $email);
```

Comment: Will this only alter the value $email if a match (gmail) is found?

Comment: Yes. Like Galen said, though, you might as well use `str_replace` if you are doing a simple string replacement.